# Does git checkout automatically fetch first?

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-fetch

Say I have a command that looks as follows:

`git checkout -b my-branch origin/dev`

Assuming I have already fetched from `origin` before, so I know it has a `dev` branch, do I **need** to run `git fetch` before `git checkout`, or will `checkout` always fetch up to the latest commit in the remote branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git checkout -b branch origin/branch` will check out from the remote repository without fetching the repository. The checked out branch will be what the branch looks like on the remote repo.

Note: Your local repository will not have the updated knowledge of the remote repository, so `git branch -a` may not show the remote branch you are checking out or it may show an older reference to it.

Comment: Thanks, this is the key idea I was looking for: _".. or it may show an older reference to it."_

Comment: As I understand it, `origin/branch` is your *local* repository's idea of what `branch` looks like on the `origin` repository. That information isn't updated unless you do an explicit `fetch` (or `pull`).

Comment: So, this doesn't really answer the question. Do I have to explicitly say `git fetch` before `git checkout` or not?